# Laravel 5.2 relationship one to one query

Tags: php, laravel-5

How i do the query to works like this example:$model->model2->attribute

```
<div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('Route name') !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', ( isset($climb->route->name) ? $climb->route->name : null ), array('class'=>'form-control' )) !!}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using your model in the view as in a dictionary, add something like this in your controller.

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$model['model2'] = $model->model2;
return view('your_view', ['model' => $model]);
```

For this I assume you already prepared your relationship in your model, doing that for your real models should make the view work this way

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Route name') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', ( isset($climb['route']['name']) ? $climb['route']['name'] : null ), array('class'=>'form-control' )) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is when i do $comment->post->title he return a array instead a object

Comment: is it really a proble it is an array instead of an object? can't you change the logic to work with an array? I'm asking this becaus according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views) the data should be an array. _"When passing information in this manner, $data should be an array with key/value pairs."_

Comment: I do the conversion the array to object function

Comment: where are you doing that? and how are you passing the data to the view? I think it could work if you do the conversion once it is in the view, though I can not be sure of that, I usually just work with arrays in the views, not really objects

Answer (score 0):

Create a relation:

Having:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post that owns the comment.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
```

Then thou shall call lika:

```
$comment = App\Comment::find(1);

echo $comment->post->title;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

It's one many, not one one I think

Comment: The problem is when i do $comment->post->title he return a array instead a object of type post

Comment: Post your post definition if it's not like that. You can cast it to an ``(object) $results`` for a dirty hack, but something seems wrong